# How to perform element-wise square root of a vector in Julia?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra, sqrt

I need to perform the square root of an array in Julia but it seems `sqrt()` function just performs square roots on scalars and square matrices.
Is there any simple compact way to do it without using loops?

Comment: Note that for square matrices, `sqrt` will give the [matrix square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix), which is not the same as the element wise square root.

Answer (score 10):

The documentation
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Array-and-Vectorized-Operators-and-Functions-1
tells you that to apply any function elementwise over an array, use the dot-broadcasting syntax:

```
sqrt.(x)
.√(x)
```

Comment: The documentation is very readable compared to that for many other languages. It's well worth a read-through.

Comment: very true but I could not find this page connected to sqrt function

Comment: The dot-broadcasting syntax works for every scalar function in Julia, including those you create yourself. So sqrt() is not special in that regard and there's no reason why you should expect dot-broadcasting to be mentioned in connection with it.